# Client side validation in MVC 4 with jQuery 1.10.2

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building an `ASP.NET MVC 4` based application and try to follow the code from the standard internet template where's possible.

Yesterday I started to implement my forms and noticed that I don't get a client side validation and the content is always submitted.

I render the form like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <ul>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
                <br />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)
                <br />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)
            </li>
            <li>
            //more list items here
```

and because I didn't start with the debugging I render the scripts as follows:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")
```

Then, in firebug, when I submit an incorrect form I get the following error:

```
TypeError: a(...).live is not a function
```

And then I saw this - `Also bear in mind that in jQuery 1.9 the .live() method has been removed which was one of the breaking changes` an another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911531/net-ajax-beginform-callback-not-fired). So I decided to try and changed the jQuery version to :

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")
```

and the validation started to work normally.

Some further research showed me that most some people made their custom `jQuery.val*` scripts in order to make it work with a new version of `jQuery`.

My question is - is there a standard packaged/bundle for client side validation that I can add to my project and use with newer version of `jQuery` (the one I'm using now is 1.10.2)? Do I have to use `jQuery 1.7.*` for my client validation parts or now there is something else supported by `MS` (like validation using `knockout.js` which is part of the standard template) or maybe even other js library that is now used for client side validation in MVC projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced similar jQuery validation problem with 1.10.2 (I would get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u").  I added the jQuery.Migrate package, and it fixed it.  I believe the error comes from a change in parseJSON.